# Effects of investment in infrastrucuture on rural migration?

Tags: infrastructure

I am not sure if this is the correct form, but when I hear or read about countries that had huge economic development in the recent past(ex: China) there is always a talk of large investment in infrastructure. I am curious to know if there was any emphasis for this investment into rural areas and if so, if this affected migration of people from rural areas to the cities as a whole?

Comment: How do you invest in rural areas while keeping them rural?

Comment: This is certainly on topic.  Not least because a lot of governments throw a lot of money to reinforce rural economies and it is interesting to see if that money is well-spent.  Or if the countryside empties anyway.